# Determine parent shell from perl

Tags: perl, shell

From perl I would like to know the name (and possibly the path) of the shell that started this perl process.

$ENV{SHELL} does not give this (it gives your login shell - but the current perl process might be started from a different shell).

The best answer I have found so far is: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=556926 but that deals terribly with different platforms (the output of 'ps' differs wildly from platform to platform).

I tried looking at %ENV, but that only contains the exported variables.

So is there a better way?

**Background**

This is to be used for GNU Parallel: Every job is started through a shell. To give the least surprise to the user, this shell should be the same shell that GNU Parallel was started from. This way a tcsh-user will be able to run his tcsh commands with GNU Parallel and the same for a bash/zsh/*sh user.

Currently $SHELL is used, but that gives the login shell and not the current shell which is surprising to users, who run a different shell than their login shell. It can also cause problems if GNU Parallel is used in a script written by a tcsh-user, but run by a bash-user.

If GNU Parallel is not started from a shell, it will default to $SHELL (same as now).

Comment: This might be slightly off topic, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish once you have the caller's shell name/path?

Comment: Who says it was a shell that started this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution became this, which does not depend on a C-compiler.

```
sub which {
    # Input:
    #   @programs = programs to find the path to
    # Returns:
    #   @full_path = full paths to @programs. Nothing if not found
    my @which;
    for my $prg (@_) {
    push @which, map { $_."/".$prg } grep { -x $_."/".$prg } split(":",$ENV{'PATH'});
    }
    return @which;
}

{
    my ($regexp,%fakename);

    sub parent_shell {
    # Input:
    #   $pid = pid to see if (grand)*parent is a shell
    # Returns:
    #   $shellpath = path to shell - undef if no shell found
    my $pid = shift;
    if(not $regexp) {
        # All shells known to mankind
        #
        # ash bash csh dash fdsh fish fizsh ksh ksh93 mksh pdksh
        # posh rbash rush rzsh sash sh static-sh tcsh yash zsh
        my @shells = qw(ash bash csh dash fdsh fish fizsh ksh
                            ksh93 mksh pdksh posh rbash rush rzsh
                            sash sh static-sh tcsh yash zsh -sh -csh);
        # Can be formatted as:
        #   [sh]  -sh  sh  busybox sh
        #   /bin/sh /sbin/sh /opt/csw/sh
        # NOT: foo.sh sshd crash flush pdflush scosh fsflush ssh
        my $shell = "(?:".join("|",@shells).")";
        $regexp = '^((\[)('. $shell. ')(\])|(|\S+/|busybox )('. $shell. '))($| )';
        %fakename = (
        # csh and tcsh disguise themselves as -sh/-csh
        "-sh" => ["csh", "tcsh"],
        "-csh" => ["tcsh", "csh"],
        );
    }
    my ($children_of_ref, $parent_of_ref, $name_of_ref) = pid_table();
    my $shellpath;
    my $testpid = $pid;
    while($testpid) {
        if($name_of_ref->{$testpid} =~ /$regexp/o) {
        $shellpath = (which($3.$6,@{$fakename{$3.$6}}))[0];
        $shellpath and last;
        }
        $testpid = $parent_of_ref->{$testpid};
    }
    return $shellpath;
    }
}

{
    my %pid_parentpid_cmd;

    sub pid_table {
    # return two tables:
    # pid -> children of pid
    # pid -> pid of parent
    # pid -> commandname

        if(not %pid_parentpid_cmd) {
        # Filter for SysV-style `ps`
        my $sysv = q( ps -ef | perl -ane '1..1 and /^(.*)CO?MM?A?N?D/ and $s=length $1;).
        q(s/^.{$s}//; print "@F[1,2] $_"' );
        # BSD-style `ps`
        my $bsd = q(ps -o pid,ppid,command -ax);
        # TODO test these on Cygwin, darwin
        %pid_parentpid_cmd =
        (
         'aix' => $sysv,
         'cygwin' => $sysv,
         'dec_osf' => $sysv,
         'darwin' => $bsd,
         'dragonfly' => $bsd,
         'freebsd' => $bsd,
         'gnu' => $sysv,
         'hpux' => $sysv,
         'linux' => $sysv,
         'mirbsd' => $bsd,
         'netbsd' => $bsd,
         'nto' => $sysv,
         'openbsd' => $bsd,
         'solaris' => $sysv,
         'svr5' => $sysv,
        );
    }
    $pid_parentpid_cmd{$^O} or die("pid_parentpid_cmd for $^O missing");

    my (@pidtable,%parent_of,%children_of,%name_of);
    # Table with pid -> children of pid
    @pidtable = `$pid_parentpid_cmd{$^O}`;
    my $p=$$;
    for (@pidtable) {
        # must match: 24436 21224 busybox ash
        /(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+.*)/ or die("pidtable format: $_");
        $parent_of{$1} = $2;
        push @{$children_of{$2}}, $1;
        $name_of{$1} = $3;
    }
    return(\%children_of, \%parent_of, \%name_of);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Proc::ProcessTable;

my $t = Proc::ProcessTable->new;

my $current_pid = $$;
my @parents;

# loop over the process table until we've found all the parents from perl pid
# up to init (process ID 1)
while ($current_pid != 1) {
    for my $process (@{ $t->table }) {
        if ($process->pid == $current_pid) {
            push @parents, $process;
            $current_pid = $process->ppid;
        }
    }
}

# loop over the parents we've found and look for something that looks like a
# shell command
for my $process (@parents) {
    my $cmd = $process->cmndline;

    if ($cmd =~ m/sh$/) {
        say $cmd;
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Proc::ProcessTable requires a C-compiler, which is not guaranteed to exist on the platform. Can we do that same without a C-compiler?