# Re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937389/determine-parent-shell-from-perl/25139489

Tags: perl

Has anyone tried this code on cygwin?

I get these errors:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ./dos_it.pl line 506.
Use of uninitialized value $shellpath in rindex at ./dos_it.pl line 586.
Use of uninitialized value $shellpath in substr at ./dos_it.pl line 586.
Use of uninitialized value $pathToShell in concatenation (.) or string at ./dos_it.pl line 761.
Use of uninitialized value $shell_conformance in concatenation (.) or string at ./dos_it.pl line 761.
```

The string that is generated is:

```
$ ps -ef | perl -ane '1..1 and /^(.*)CO?MM?A?N?D/ and $s=length $1;s/^.{$s}//; print "@F[1,2] $_"'
```

Perl version:

```
$ perl -v    
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 2 (v5.26.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

Comment: Most likely you are running that oneliner under `cmd.exe` and not the cygwin shell. This would easily explain the error message, as Perl should never see a single quote under a sh-compatible shell.

Answer (score 1):

That is a command for the Bourne shell (`sh`) or similar, but you gave it to the Windows shell (`cmd`) to execute. Execute the command using `sh` or similar (whether cygwin-built or otherwise) to get rid of the error.

By the way, you were using a Windows build of Perl (`MSWin32-x64` arch), not a cygwin build of Perl (`cygwin` arch). That's not the cause of the error, as the program will run fine either way. That said, this "issue" will surely go away once you use a cygwin-built `sh` or similar to execute the command.

Comment: The command was issued in cygwin's version of Bash.  I didn't run it in either the DOS cmd window nor in Powershell.   So, the sub-command is actually spawning a DOS cmd shell ??

Comment: Upon further investigation, the PERL5SHELL controls what Perl uses for executing backtick commands.  Its default is claimed to be cmd.exe. So, I need to make sure that it is set to cygwin's Bash value.

Comment: Or make sure to use a cygwin build of Perl